# How to copy data from an excel file (different sheets) into one text file using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to copy data from different excel sheets into one csv file using python. I require the output to be in a specific layout and to have conditions for 2 of the fields. If the first name field and any of the fields in the 'bank' sheet are blank i need the field to be populated with 'No first name' and 'No bank details' for their respective fields. Each sheet needs it own line item for a record which is linked using the customer code field. I am very new to Python but assume it will be better then using a VBA like I am currently using.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/675FS.png)

[Data in excel sheet Customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7NXw.png) [Sheet address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDoZu.png) [sheet bank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bgFk.png) [contacts sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ALs2.png)
[Output should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWb1u.png)

Comment: Can anyone assist with a script that I can work from or develop onto?

Comment: I have added an image of a script I have worked on but its still not what I require, can someone please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [xlrd library](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/). You can check out the documentation and some examples at their Github page [here](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/tree/master/docs)

Comment: Please can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas. (pip install pandas)
It is by far the most easy ways if you don't want to get into file, readers etc.

This 10 minutes guide will be sufficient for it:)
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

I did the same thing with my project, so be safe it is the best way.
 Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Ashish, do you have a base script I can work off of and learn from, I am very new to Python and am looking for an alternative to VBA for this task.